# Java newbie problem: classes of the same package accessing one another?

Tags: java, package

The classes belong to the same pkg. They are in the dir, name of the pkg.

- In general, how can classes access one another in the same pkg?

**Error**

```
javac PackTest.java
PackTest.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class PriTest
location: class pacc.PackTest
  System.out.println(new PriTest().getSaluto());
                         ^
1 error
```

**Classes in the PKG pacc**

```
$ cat PackTest.java 
package pacc;
import java.io.*;

public class PackTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(new PriTest().getSaluto());
    }
}
$ cat PriTest.java 
package pacc;

public class PriTest
{
    public PriTest(){}
    private String saluto="SALUTO FROM PriTest";
    public String getSaluto(){return saluto;}
}
```

**PKG of the name of dir**

```
$  find .. -type d -name "pacc"
../pacc
$ ls ../pacc 
makefile  PackTest.java  PriTest.java
$ ls
makefile  PackTest.java  PriTest.java
```

**Solved!**

```
$ cat makefile 
p:
    javac ./pacc/PackTest.java
    java pacc/PackTest
$ make p
javac ./pacc/PackTest.java
java pacc/PackTest
SALUTO FROM PriTest
```

Comment: @HH: I've noticed that you've been asking lots of questions on Java lately: you should invest some time and install an IDE. It'd make your time considerably more productive. I recommend eclipse.org

Comment: @poly: I have broken it too many times, the project needs fast modifications. When the project is more frozen, I will but not yet.

Comment: The point of an IDE is to be able to be make those fast modifications.  Also, wildcard imports are lazy -- Eclipse can help you get rid of those.

Comment: @HH, Eclipse is an extremely mature and stable Java IDE.  As long as you're not pulling the source from trunk and compiling it yourself it should work very well.  The Galileo release has been out for a while and I've never had any issues with it.  You might want to invest the hour or two to get it installed and familiarize yourself with it.  If you have problems just ask a question here and I'm sure it will be answered quickly.

Comment: Using an IDE you don't need to worry about silly things like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAYBE (So don't kill me, please) this is a solution:

In the terminal, go to the root of your java project (so the default package, in your situation, the parent directory of the folder `pacc`).
Then type: `javac pacc.PackTest.java`

I don't use the compiler manually. My IDE does that work for me.

Comment: This observation actually lead to the solution. Accepted because it is the CRUX move.

Comment: You need to be one dir down. So you need to run commands like "$ javac ./pacc/PackTest.java; java pacc/PackTest", see the makefile.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the files are in the same directory, with the same name as the package. Also, make sure the classpath is set correctly.

Packages mimic the directory structure - "Test.java" in package "org.example.test" should be found at "org/example/test/Test.java".

The following compiled your files for me:

```
 $ javac -cp "." *.java
```

And I ran with

```
 $ cd ..
 $ java pacc.PackTest
```

No problems here.

BTW Apache Ant is generally preferred over makefiles in the Java universe.

Comment: the last thing has the err: the path is wrong. I supposed it to be "SetWord.java" not "tools/setWord.java". I can solve by making the classes independent of one another in the tools-dir -- but is there some easier way to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean here.

Comment: Adrian Mouat: I have a package tools that has "scissor", "camera", "spell", "setWord", "sanitise" -- how can you access sanitise with the class "spell"?

Comment: If they're both public classes, both in the "tools" package and both in the same directory, it should work.

Comment: You've now edited the question substantially - it's really a different question. Try adding "." to the classpath though.

Comment: @Adrian: 'Try adding "." to the classpath'?

Comment: @Adrian: please, see the makefile. Even with the recent mod the same err

Comment: And if you compile *.java rather than just PackTest.java?

Comment: SOLVED: the err was "./", please, see the makefile. It should be very easy to replicate with the sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you are used to the C and C++ approach of compiling each file separately, you may be surprised to learn that the Java compiler works best when you give it your **entire project** to compile all at once.

[Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) is a commonly used tool for building Java projects.  It does the job of calling `javac` for you.  It works better for Java than `make(1)` does.

---

Compile as:

```
H:\test\so>javac pacc/PackTest.java pacc/PriTest.java
```

You should be in the **root** of your project, not in the folder `pacc`.

Comment: No, you never need to import classes from the same package.

Answer (score 0):

Get an ide like IntelliJ IDEA. Java is so complex and bloated this will help so you need not even bother with such trivial things.

Answer (score 0):

Once you master the fundamentals, an IDE is an essential productivity tool.

Until then, it's good for you to think through these problems to gain a deeper understanding of Java development.

As far as ANT, it is worth your time to move to that now. Makefiles don't offer you any further edification of programming.